# Surprised that removeChangeListener(null) doesn't throw NullPointerException

Tags: java, swing, null, changelistener

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
        JTabbedPane tab = new JTabbedPane();
        tab.removeChangeListener(null);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

this doesn't result in a `NullPointerException`.

what exactly happens when I call `tab.removeChangeListener(null)`?

Answer (score 1):

> ***what exactly happens when I call tab.removeChangeListener(null)?***

exactly this:

in **JTabbedPane** this method is invoked:

```
public void removeChangeListener(ChangeListener l) {
    listenerList.remove(ChangeListener.class, l);
}
```

where  the `listenerList`  is declared as `protected EventListenerList listenerList = new EventListenerList();`

and the remove method is:

```
public synchronized <T extends EventListener> void remove(Class<T> t, T l) {
    if (l ==null) {
        // In an ideal world, we would do an assertion here
        // to help developers know they are probably doing
        // something wrong
        return;
    }
    ...
    ...
```

so, removing a null is just returning leaving the listener unaffected